# Import jar files while rebuilding an entire project in Eclipse with .jar files only

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, .class-file

I need to rebuild an entire project into Eclipse.
I just have .jar files which contain only .class files.

There are plenty of .jar files located in a lot of directories, how can I do that easily?

Comment: What kind of project is it Java Project or Web Project ?

Comment: It is a Java Project

Comment: Consider explaining how you are building your project, in your question itself, not in comments.